# Seminal Books of fMRI

Tags: neuroimaging, fmri

I would like to know what books about fMRI do people consider as key or seminal. I am very familiar with a great amonut of MRI techniques, but I am sort of looking for a book in fMRI that really considers the root of the technique (as for teaching material). As a guideline, I consider the book of Diffusion MRI by Derek Jones as being the gold standard: mathematical, physics, biological and clinical considerations. So I guess that the question is what would you consider the fMRI equivalent to Derek's exhaustive book. Maybe even some reviews that you consider important and you yourselfs are (co-) authors.

Best and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one book that many people hold in high regard is Human Brain Function by J. Ashburner, W. Penny and K. Friston. It is old but it covers the principles nicely. It is also freely available online: https://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/doc/books/hbf2/

I guess you will be most interested in material from section 2 onwards.

Comment: This was useful. I was not aware of it. Thank you very much!